# Edate cannot have nested function call?

Tags: google-sheets

Why is it that this function does not display a date in Google Spreadsheets?

```
=edate(today(),6)
```

I am trying to display the date that is 6 months from today. Instead, the cell only shows a value like this: 41,797.

It seems that I cannot embed the function call to `today()` inside of the `edate` function. If I run the `today()` function and store it in one cell, and then reference the cell from the `edate()` function, ONLY THEN does it work.

Are you not allowed to nest function calls in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing it correct, only the format is wrong. There are two ways to resolve that problem:

1. Select the cell or range and goto the menu and select `Format`, followed by `Number`. In the date section you can choose the appropriate date format.
2. Use the following formula: 
   `=DATEVALUE(EDATE(TODAY(),6))`

   This will convert the integer (41,797) into a date notation. See screenshot:
   [image]